# New ACM Latex compilation error: ! pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable fonts

Tags: fonts, pdftex, fontsize, acm, font-expansion

I'm trying to compile the new ACM latex template for my camera ready paper provided in http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~lu/CPSWeek2017-Typesetting/

This template doesn't compile for me and shows following error:

```
! pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable
fonts.
\@EveryShipout@Output ...@Org@Shipout \box \@cclv
```

How can I fix it? It is the template! No changes.

```
! pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable
fonts.
\@EveryShipout@Output ...@Org@Shipout \box \@cclv
l.121 \end{enumerate}
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
18161 strings out of 493698
267992 string characters out of 3144404
402755 words of memory out of 3000000
20985 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
54348 words of font info for 144 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
1186 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
60i,11n,94p,1105b,468s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

P.S. Interestingly when I use an online compiler such as Sharelatex, it looks fine.

P.S. 2: Thanks to everybody, especially Boris: I re-installed the `liberty` font on miktex package manager, but that changes made my miktex not work for unknown reasons! I re-installed the whole miktex packages from scratch using `ProText` and now I can compile :)

Comment: Compiles fine with pdflatex from texlive2016. Which tex distribution are you using? And which tex engine?

Comment: @samcarter I'm using MikTex with Texmaker application: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
**

Comment: Interestingly when I use an online compiler such as sharelatex.com, it looks good!

Comment: Could you please post the log?

Comment: @TinaJ Sounds reasonable up-to-date. Can you make a copy of `sample-sigconf.tex` and `acmart.cls` and remove stuff as long as the error is still present? This will narrow down the source of your problem.

Comment: I added full logs for the error. Unfortunately the whole thing was too long I couldn't add

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The new version of the ACM template changed the font used by it, calling many free fonts typically available in TeX distributions. It might be the case that some  of the required fonts (libertine or newtx fonts) are not installed in your distribution.

Comment: Try installing `cm-super`.

Comment: @Guido If the fonts were absent, the error would be different. The problem is that it finds the fonts, but they are not scalable. That is, it is finding fonts for which standard distributions include both source and type1, but for which the OP only has source, whereas the template assumes type1.

Comment: Could you send me your logs by e-mail?  My address is in the `acmart` documentation.

Comment: Use of `\lmodern` helps compiling, but the output is a bit different with what I compiled online.

Comment: @Boris I couldn't find your email. I pasted it here: https://justpaste.it/14j6l

Comment: borisv@lk.net - on the first page of the documentation

Comment: @Boris Just sent